# -bash: vagrant: command not foundと出てコマンドが実行出来ない

Tags: shell

ターミナルに行き、

```
vagrant init bento/centos-6.7
```

と入力すると、

```
-bash: vagrant: command not found
```

と表示が出てしまいファイルが作成できません。対処方法を教えてください。
MacOSです。

Comment: エラーメッセージを省略されてますか？もしそうでしたら省略せずに書いてもらえますか？メッセージは「コメント」ではなくて質問を「編集」して追記してください

Comment: 「Vagrantでcent osを立ち上げ」というのは、具体的にどのようなコマンドを実行していますか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`command not found` というのは、シェルがコマンドを見つけられなかったという事です。
シェルは`$PATH`で設定されているディレクトリのリストから実行ファイルを探しますが、その中には無かったという事です。

まず、自分で探す必要があります。
インストールしたディレクトリ以下にある筈ですので、めぼしい所（Macなら`/usr/local`、 `/opt`、`/Application`、あるいはホームディレクトリあたりに適当にインストールされているのではないでしょうか）を

```
find /usr/ /opt/ /Applications/ ~/ -name vagrant 2>/dev/null
```

などとして検索してもよいでしょう。

実行ファイルを発見したら、フルパスで指定し実行出来ます。
例えば`/opt/vagrant/bin/vagrant`が見つかったなら、

```
/opt/vagrant/bin/vagrant
```

とすればよいです。

いちいちフルパスを入力するのが面倒であったり、他のコマンドから呼び出されエラーになっている場合は、

- 当該実行ファイルのリンクをパス（$PATH）の通っているディレクトリの中に作成する
- パス（$PATH）に当該実行ファイルが置かれているディレクトリを追加する

のいずれかを行ないます。

Comment: ありがとうございます。Linuxを理解から出直します…